# How to find a rotation angle of Transform3d in Java3D after rotating by mouse or keynavigator?

Tags: java, java-3d

We are working on a augmented reality project wherein the user will be able to virtually place 3d objects on 2d image.

We are able to place the 3d object (obj file) on 2d image, java 3d allows me dynamically rotate the object using KeyNavigator and ViewingPlatform class, but I am not able to detect the new angle of the object.

Can you tell me on how to detect the Changed Angle of the 3d object?